# How to Resolve Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response and Cross Origin errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, axios

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.set("data", "C://Users//harshit.tDownloads\\weather.csv");
      bodyFormData.set("type", "text-intent");
      //axios.post("https://api.einstein.ai/v2/language/datasets/upload", 

      axios({
         method: 'post',
         url: 'https://xxxx/v2/language/datasets/upload',
         data: bodyFormData,
          mode: 'bodyFormData',
         //dataType:'json',
         headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer IFMEWWRWLJGTOSBWIJFEIQSCJJFVIVSEG5NEWNSKIRGTOTKQIRKDMUKQGJBFETCFJ5GUENSSIJHUEQJWIFHE4NSWIZHE6TCFGVJUMV2VLFIUKVSPKBMEMNKRGVJFMU2KIRIUUQKMIFIU2R2ZGNJFSTSRIQZEUN2GIVFFC7COIE',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,

            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST',

            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*'

         }
      })
         .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log("1111111",response);
         })
         .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
         });
```

How to Resolve Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response and Cross Origin errors while calling api from axios ,I am getting CORS ERROR please check the above code

Comment: You can either solve this in the backend using an NPM package called CORS. Or you can use the chrome extension "Allow CORS" for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the nodejs server, you could use the next middleware after installing it with `npm install cors`

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Who say he has access to the backend? It could be someone elses

Comment: I was assuming he has control. I agree with you. Edited.

Comment: I don't have backend access, am using react js  for calling the api